# Add camera preview as layer for Mapview in Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-camera, android-mapview, nutiteq

Currently, I'm working on a App which contain Map. in this I would like to add my camera preview as Mapview's background or layer. which means, All place markers shows only one my camera preview. [image: Like this] . Actually concept behind in this is, when I open my camera activity, it's shows nearby place marker on it. so when I click that marker, it's shows popup which contains place details. as shown in image. How can I implement this please. please give me any idea. I have tried with camera preview on background and mapview on foreground and setAlpha(0);, and remove all layers on mapview and so on. nothing workout for me. Kindly help me to found out the solution. Thanks in advance.

Update:

This is how I have add my camera preview:

```
 FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    cameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(this);
    preview.addView(cameraSurfaceView);
```

and this is how I have add my MapView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.nutiteq.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>


   mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

I have tried to `mapView.setAlpha(0f);` but this hide mapview together with marker. nothing could see .

I have tried to set

```
Canvas can =  new Canvas();
can.drawColor(0x7FFFFFFF);
mapView.draw(can);
```

but this one also not works.

there is some method called `addLayer();` but I don't know how to convert my camera preview as layer.

Comment: can you provide some code snippet

Comment: Do R & D on this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mixare

Comment: Its an app of augmented reality

Comment: Ayto-Droid@ Yes I'm looking on it. hope this one helps me, once I done I let you know. Thanks a lot Buddy.. You Rocks!!!

Comment: When I run this sample app, i got error called VM aborting. Fatel signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeaddood (code=1), thread 7855 (org.mixare).. do you know , why it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I was totally wrong by my concept. Now everything goes well after looking into **augmented reality** concepts. now I'm using BeyondAR Agumented Reality SDK from here [enter link description here](http://beyondar.com/) .

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid using Nutiteq `MapView` on top of other views is not possible. `MapView` is based on `GLSurfaceView` class and its ordering vs other views is limited - it can be only the bottom most view. This is a `GLSurfaceView` limitation in Android.

Comment: Hi Mark, you are right, `Nutiteq MapView` doesn't behave like i.e. `Android MapView` and that'd be a Problem i.e. to inflate a `View` whose parent is a `Nutiteq MapView`, so that `inflate` Method needs a `ViewGroup` parent Parameter and `Nutiteq Mapview` doesn't inherit from `ViewGroup` but ``Android.View`, so what I think, RathaKrishna wants is just a capture of a `View` as `drawable` and that's independent of `Nutiteq`, that's just `android.view` dependent not `ViewGroup` dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood right, you want a `drawable` of a `camera preview` as background, don't you?

If that's what you want, then you can capture or screenshot your `camera preview` View like this

```
# Build the Drawing Cache
view.buildDrawingCache();

# Create Bitmap
Bitmap cache = view.getDrawingCache();

# Save Bitmap
saveBitmap(cache);
view.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Then you could work with this screenshot as you want.

I hope, this could help you.

Kind Regards

p.s. I found this info [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) to capture sights of my Views and since then I often use it.